take measures to-infinitive

We must take preventive measures to reduce crime in the area.

[Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary]
Is the bold part adjectival or adverbial? I am wavering between the following two analyses:
(1) We must take preventive measures that will reduce crime in the area.
(2) We must take preventive measures in order to reduce crime in the area.

I don't think it's the to-infinitive. I think it's the preposition "to" followed by the bare infinitive. I realise this could start a completely pointless discussion....

In English language education in Japan, the preposition "to" followed by a bare infinitive is called a to-infinitive.


We must take preventive measures to reduce crime in the area.

Both interpretations (adjectival and adverbial) of to reduce crime in the area
are possible.  To further illustrate that, we could also interpret the sentence to mean
[Preventive measures [to reduce crime in the area]] must be taken.
or
To reduce crime in the area, we must take preventive measures.
Whichever way we interpret is fine as it doesn't affect the meaning of the sentence.

Thank you. I think that "to reduce crime in the area" in "Preventive measures must be taken to reduce crime in the area" is adverbial. Am I correct?

Hi, @Kaguyahime, Yes, it is adverbial in this case as it is shown to be detachable from measures.  Adjectival phrases, on the other hand, are usually together with their modificands.
